# C# Path.Combine is not using AppData location

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access the `AppData` folder to create/delete directories as needed but using `Path.Combine` is yielding only half the desired path. Here's what I have:

```
string sPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string test = Path.Combine(sPath, @"\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\SkillControl\");
```

The test string is in place of a `Directory.CreateDirectory` which is the next line (when working). Here are the results of debugging these lines:

```
sPath: "C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Roaming"
test: "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\SkillControl\\"
```

I was expecting "test" to result in the full path:

```
C:\\Users\\[User]\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\SkillControl\\
```

but it seems to ignore the combine function. Can anyone work out why?

To clarify before it's asked, `sPath` is just a way for me to confirm if `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` was pulling the correct location which it is, I get the same results when doing

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
@"Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\SkillControl\"));
```

Comment: as @Daisy said you should not use `\` or `\\` to combine path the combine method would do that. you can try this for ex: 
`var sPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
 var final = Path.Combine(sPath,"Microsoft","windows","Start Menu");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second path is an absolute path - it starts with a backslash. The method is behaving [as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2.

Just remove the leading backslash and it should be fine.

```
string sPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string test = Path.Combine(sPath, @"Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\SkillControl\");
```

Comment: I was wondering what it meant by an absolute path, I tried removing the @ symbol and adding double slashes instead (obviously it didn't work) I'll try this in a second

Comment: @RufusL: Fixed, thanks. (When I answered, the question had a truncated first line, and I hadn't spotted that bit.)